# Mongodb nested document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
var DateOnly = require('mongoose-dateonly')(mongoose);

const HealthSchema = new Schema({
  temprature: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  date: {
    type:DateOnly,
    default: Date.now,
  },

});
const PredictionSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  
  healtData: [HealthSchema]
  
});

module.exports = Prediction = mongoose.model("Prediction",  PredictionSchema);
```

I am creating referance id for this schema in userSchema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  predictionId:{
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Prediction",
  }
})
```

My question is,
for this given schema I want to fetch temperature for given date and given user.I am giving referance id to PredictionSchema for all users.How can i do so?

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 1):

- `$match` you user id condition
- `$lookup` with prediction collection and pass prediction id in `let`,
- `$match` prediction id condition and date condition

```
let userId = 1; // convert to object id using mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)
let date = new Date("2020-12-01");
let startDate = new Date(new Date(date).setUTCHours(00,00,00,000));
let endDate = new Date(new Date(date).setUTCHours(23,59,59,999));

User.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: userId } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "predictions",
      let: { predictionId: "$predictionId" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$predictionId"] },
            "healtData.date": {
              $gte: startDate,
              $lte: endDate
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "Prediction"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GD7gFFKNI53)